# Concatenate database query result to a string

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to take the single result from a SQL query and concatenate it to a string. Using SQL Server and Visual Studios.

```
            Dim Password As SqlDataReader
            cmd.CommandText = "Select Password from tblLogin where Username = '" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' and EmailAddress = '" & EmailAddressTextBox.Text & "'"
            Password = cmd.ExecuteReader
            EmailMessage.Body = ("Your password is: " & Password)
```

The error I am getting is that I cannot use the operator & with Password.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified I am using a SQL server and Visual Studios.

Comment: you have multiple problems.  Password is a SQL reserved word with most DBs and ExecuteReader is going to return an object *containing* the password.

Comment: Isn't that what I need?  An object that contains the password so that I can send the password through email?

Comment: the error message is tell you that you cannot glue a SqlDataReader to a string.  get the password string out of the poorly named Password container first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Password variable in your code is a SQLDataReader object, not a string.  It can have many values, so you need to get the part you want out of it. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

```
    If Password.HasRows Then 
        Do While Password.Read()
            EmailMessage.Body = ("Your password is: " & Password.GetString(0))
        Loop 
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.")
    End If
```

I would also recommend changing the Password SQLDataREader to a different name, just to make it less confusing.

Comment: Whats the 0 for inside GetString(0)?

Comment: it is to get the first value in the row returned (the row is like a 0-based array, so you start with 0 (zero) instead of 1